# Compiled slug size is too large (max is 500M) due to "sentence-transformers" in Heroku

Tags: heroku, deployment, slug, sentence-transformers, semantic-search

I am receiving this error while deploying my application on Heroku:
[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p1pj0.png)

It is because I have added "sentence-transformers" to my applications requirements.txt file and If I don't install "sentence-transformers" the application is deployed successfully but it is not functional.

Is there any way I can use "sentence-transformers" semantic_search feature without hitting the slug size error?

Thank you!

I tried deploying an application with "sentence-transformers" on Heroku.

Comment: Please read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/354577) You can [edit] your question and replace the images with [code block]s. The easiest way to do this is to paste the code as text directly into your question, then select it and click the code block button.

Comment: You're not over by just a little bit: 2.7G is _way_ too big for Heroku. I'm not familiar with "sentence-transformers", but lots of ML / NLP libraries include huge amounts of data. Assuming that's the case here, Heroku might not be the best fit for your application.